# Get posts from a Facebook page by date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, filter

Facebook Page is a useful channel for us to study something. But I have a problem in filter its posts by date: get all posts by a specified date. The old posts are floated.

Is there any Facebook API supporting to do this task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the parameters `since` and `until` in conjuntion with *strtotime*

`strtotime();` **reference:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Example of usage using Graph API Explorer.

```
// example will return first 20 posts made between 15th of March, and 5th of April 2013.
example.com/feed?since=15+march+2013&until=5+april+2013&limit=20
```

**Live example:**

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/135669679827333/?method=GET&path=shawndageek%2Ffeed%3Fsince%3D1%20january%202015%26until%3Dnow%26limit%3D20&version=v2.5

**Additional info:**

- Post objects return with most recent first, so if an older post is not showing you may need to close the date gap or increase the `limit=`